# Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with (DCMTK) and LNK2038/LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, runtime, dcmtk

I'm using DCMTK 3.6.1 library in a project in Visual Studio 2013 with C++ language. My code works perfectly in Debug mode but not in Release mode; When I try to compile it I have 275 errors all like this:

dcmdata.lib(dcdatset.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for

```
'_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dcdatset.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dcfilefo.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dcfilefo.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dcxfer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dcxfer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dctagkey.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dctagkey.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dctag.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dctag.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in testapp_new.obj
2>dcmdata.lib(dcstack.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in testapp_new.obj
```

I have tried a lot of solution found on the web but nothing work...

If I try to compile the DCMTL library in Release mode, I have this errors:

```
Error   4   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmdjpls.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(intrface.obj)
Error   5   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmdjpls.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(header.obj)
Error   6   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmdjpls.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(jpegls.obj)
Error   7   error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)
Error   8   error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   9   error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   10  error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   11  error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   12  error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   13  error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   14  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)
Error   15  error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   16  error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   17  error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   18  error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   19  error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   20  error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)
Error   21  error LNK2005: __calloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crtheap.obj)
Error   22  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)
Error   23  error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   24  error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   25  error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   26  error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   27  error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)
Error   28  error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)
Error   29  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj)
Error   30  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   31  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   32  error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(wsetloca.obj)
Error   33  error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)
Warning 34  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LINK
Warning 35  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LINK
Error   36  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\bin\Release\dcmdjpls.exe
Error   37  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcml2pnm.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(intrface.obj)
Error   38  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcml2pnm.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(header.obj)
Error   39  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcml2pnm.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(jpegls.obj)
Error   40  error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)
Error   41  error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   42  error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   43  error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   44  error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   45  error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   46  error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   47  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)
Error   48  error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   49  error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   50  error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   51  error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   52  error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   53  error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)
Error   54  error LNK2005: __calloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crtheap.obj)
Error   55  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)
Error   56  error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   57  error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   58  error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   59  error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   60  error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)
Error   61  error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)
Error   62  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj)
Error   63  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   64  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   65  error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(wsetloca.obj)
Error   66  error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)
Warning 67  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LINK
Warning 68  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LINK
Error   69  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\bin\Release\dcml2pnm.exe
Error   70  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmcjpls.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(intrface.obj)
Error   71  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmcjpls.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(header.obj)
Error   72  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmcjpls.obj C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\charls.lib(jpegls.obj)
Error   73  error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)
Error   74  error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   75  error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   76  error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   77  error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   78  error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   79  error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   80  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)
Error   81  error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   82  error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   83  error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   84  error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   85  error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   86  error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)
Error   87  error LNK2005: __calloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crtheap.obj)
Error   88  error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)
Error   89  error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   90  error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   91  error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   92  error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   93  error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)
Error   94  error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)
Error   95  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj)
Error   96  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   97  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   98  error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LIBCMT.lib(wsetloca.obj)
Error   99  error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)
Warning 100 warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LINK
Warning 101 warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmjpls\apps\LINK
Error   102 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\bin\Release\dcmcjpls.exe
Error   103 error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmsend.obj  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\charls.lib(intrface.obj)
Error   104 error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmsend.obj  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\charls.lib(header.obj)
Error   105 error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in dcmsend.obj  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\charls.lib(jpegls.obj)
Error   106 error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj)
Error   107 error LNK2005: ___crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   108 error LNK2005: ___crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   109 error LNK2005: ___crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winapisupp.obj)
Error   110 error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   111 error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   112 error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
Error   113 error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)
Error   114 error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   115 error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   116 error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   117 error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   118 error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj)
Error   119 error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(dosmap.obj)
Error   120 error LNK2005: __calloc_crt already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crtheap.obj)
Error   121 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj)
Error   122 error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   123 error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   124 error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   125 error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj)
Error   126 error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj)
Error   127 error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)  C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj)
Error   128 error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj)
Error   129 error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   130 error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj)
Error   131 error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll) C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\LIBCMT.lib(wsetloca.obj)
Error   132 error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fileno.obj)   C:\dcmtk-bin_2\dcmnet\apps\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)
```

do you have any idea how solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following an advice in the DCMTK official Forum, I have recompiled the DCMTK library with the flag DCMTK_OVERWRITE_WIN32_COMPILER_FLAGS disabled and now I'm able to compile in Debug/Release mode, so works!

I need to install the library in Debug mode and after in Release mode

In any case I will investigate more on this stuffs.

Comment: I hate it when library authors think they know better than the build system. Because then stuff like this happens. Glad you found a way out!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing both Debug/Release and Dynamic/Static libraries.

In the first go, you have

```
mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'
```

In the second go, you have:

```
mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'
```

So you replaced dynamic+debug with static+release. You solved half the problem but messed up the other half!

I suggest recompiling the library but in the dynamic+release configuration. Or compile your project in the static+release configuration, but what you want is up to you of course.

Comment: How I can recompiling the library but in the dynamic+release configuration ?? 

After I have downloaded the library, I generate the DCMTK solution with Cmake and if I try to compile the DCMTK solution in Debug mode works, the same in Release mode doesn't work

Comment: @GiordiX You can usually run CMake with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` (or set the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable in the GUI). You should be able to set the `/MT`-family of options when running CMake's configure step.

Comment: I don't have any `xxxx_BUILD_TYPE` flag. I have the `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPE = Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo`  that are the various configuration that I can see inside the solution. There is the Debug;Release as you can see so I expected it to work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" anyway? Some compiler error or what?

Comment: Compile error. But I solved thanks to an asnwer in the DCMTK official forum. Look down. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the libraries you are using are compiler with a different VS version. So you can fix this only if you recompile the library you got.

Or you used different settings for the use of the CRT (static and dynamic linking).

Look into the [readmes](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_install.html)! They don't mention VS-2013!

Is it possible that you use a compiler flag to ignore the default libraries? This is never a good way if you use static libraries created with other VS versions.

Comment: So you think that the library are not compatible with VS2013? But they works perfectly in Debug mode and a lot of people use this library with VS2013. I think they only forgot to update the readmes, because the last revised is old: 2011-01-06

Comment: My answer is based on the linker errors I see. And for me it seams that the libraries that are used, are not build with the same compiler. Or you used different compiler settings for static and dynamic use of the CRT!